# Python List Multiplication

Tags: python, list, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am currently trying to run the following code

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:/Users/j.png') 

WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size

imgData = list(img.getdata())  =
imgData = [imgData[offset:offset + WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH * HEIGHT, WIDTH)]

def function_sum2_x():
    sum2_x = 0
    for i in range(0, HEIGHT - 1):
        for j in range(0, WIDTH - 1):
            sum2_x += imgData[i][j] * imgData[i][j]

    return sum2_x

print(function_sum2_x())
```

Although I am getting the following error:
line 25, in function_sum2_x
    sum2_x += imgData[i][j] * imgData[i][j]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

The purpose of this code is for a mathematical formula for comparing 2 images.  For context, my image is black and white binary. I originally thought the issue would be due to multiplying the 0 values by eachother in "imgData" but after converting all 0s to 1s I am getting the same issue.

After some research online I found some issues with list multiplication so now I think this may be the issue. I found some sources saying to use the line

```
newarr= map(lambda x: i*x, imgData)
```

However I am not sure how to implement this and if it is actually useful to resolving this error

Comment: What do `img.mode` and `img.info` show you?  I think your imagine is color even though you think it is B&W, that's why each pixel is a tuple instead of a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a colored image, use [`Image.convert()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) to convert it to a grayscale image. Even though your image is black and white in your image viewer, it does not mean that it's saved that way internally.

Comment: Yea I was using code to convert images to BW Binary but this 1 image slipped through the cracks. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the question as solved - this saves time to people who don't want to read alread answered questions.